# Conditional where to eliminate duplication in hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

How can I to simplify next where clause?:

```
    where
        e.withdrawalMonth is null
        and ((:debt = 1 and not exists
            (from
            PaidConcept cc
                join cc.invoice i
             where
             cc.enrollment = e
             and cc.month = m
             and cc.concept = co
             and i.status = 'PAID'
            ))
         or(:debt = 0 and exists
            (from
            PaidConcept cc
                join cc.invoice i
             where
             cc.enrollment = e
             and cc.month = m
             and cc.concept = co
             and i.status = 'PAID'
            ))
        )
```

There are two equal subqueries, but first is `not exists` and second is `exists` I want to run first when `debt` parameter is 1 and last when `debt` parameter is 0.

How can be it be made more DRY?

Answer (score 0):

```
String subquery = (from
            PaidConcept cc
                join cc.invoice i
             where
             cc.enrollment = e
             and cc.month = m
             and cc.concept = co
             and i.status = 'PAID'
            ))

String query = "where e.withdrawalMonth is null 
      + " and ((:debt = 1 and not exists "
      + subquery 
      + " or(:debt = 0 and exists " 
      + subquery + ")"
```

Comment: That is not a hibernate or hql response my friend. That is a Java response. I must read the hql from file and execute it. Language agnostic.